# Отлавливание левой и правой кнопки мыши в Unity при нажатии на Button. C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно отлавливать кнопки мыши, при нажатии на button - UI элемент? Мне нужно запускать скрипт через Event Trigger при нажатии и отжатии левой кнопки мыши, а правую игнорировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще реакция на правую кнопку мыши отключается в
Edit > Project Settings > Input

> (найдено по запросу в гугле "unity button ignore right click" по первой ссылке)

Но можно и просто написать свою реализацию кнопки которая это будет делать. Это так же просто в реализации.

Comment: Не подскажите по подробнее?

Comment: не, у меня сейчас юнити не установлен. А что, не видно в инпуте ничего такого?

Comment: Судя по скриншотам в интернете окна инпут это будет одна из дочерних настроек "Submit", вероятнее всего "type"

Comment: А разве она не на все кнопки повлияет?

Comment: Хочешь что бы повлияло только на одну копку - реализуй собственную кнопку которая будет реагировать только на левый клик. Это мало кода. В чем конкретно проблема? Я тебе дал целых 2 пути решения указанной проблемы. Не нравится один - используй второй.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы отлавливать нажатие по Button в Unity тебе нужно создать специальный класс, который будет наследовать интерфейс `IPointerClickHandler`.
Этот класс должен быть добавлен компонентом к объекту, на котором у тебя висит Button. Чтобы этот интерфейс появился в IntelliSense не забудь добавить `using UnityEngine.EventSystems;`

Далее, в методе `OnPointerClick` ты сможешь перехватить нажатие. Не важно, как именно добавлено событие к твоей Button, через скрипт или через inspector.
Теперь ты можешь отследить, какая именно кнопка мыши была нажата и если это не левая кнопка мыши-тогда ты просто сбрасываешь вызов через `eventData.Reset();`

Привожу небольшой пример кода ниже.

```c#
public class TESTTEST : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{

    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
        {
            Debug.Log("Left click");

        }
        else if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Middle)
        {
            Debug.Log("Middle click");
            eventData.Reset();
        }
        else if (eventData.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Right)
        {
            Debug.Log("Right click");
            eventData.Reset();
        }
    }

    public void ActiveOnLeft()
    {
        Debug.Log("ActiveOnLeft");
    }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.

Comment: Спасибо Антону за редактирование)